# Efficiently matching Regex stored in Redis with my input

Tags: php, regex, redis

Is is possible to store efficiently match regex patterns stored in Redis Set/Hash and match my input in an efficient manner?
My Current approach is to first look up the patterns that I need to match my input against, followed by actually doing a 'preg_match'. This is slightly cumbersome and not efficient. Can someone help me make it efficient? I am using predis client library.
How things are stored in my redis:

```
SADD regex [a-z]+[1-9]+@ prorogue[0-9]+@ ... and so on.
```

Comment: What does your code currently look like? And please clarify why you find it cumbersome and inefficient.

Comment: I find it cumbersome because I think it is computationally exhaustive to fetch every regex from Redis(there could be hundreds of them) and then  match your input against it.

Comment: So you need to match a string against regex patterns stored in Redis as a set, correct? Well, I don't see a more efficient way of doing that other than getting them from Redis and then doing a preg_match unless you can restructure the data (for example, store all patterns in a single key instead of a set).

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using Redis' built-in Lua scripting capabilities. Lua offers pattern matching functions (e.g. `string.match`) but note that

> Unlike several other scripting languages, Lua does not use POSIX regular expressions (regexp) for pattern matching (http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html)

In pseudo-Redis-Lua code, this would look something like:

```
local re = redis.call("SMEMBERS", KEYS[1])
for _, r in pairs(re) do
  if string.match(ARGV[1], r) then
    return 1
  end
end
return 0
```